# fork and wait for child process doesn't seem to wait at all

Tags: c, linux, shell

we are creating a simple shell process.

here is the code:

```
pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1) {
            printf("fork error");

        }else if (pid > 0) {
            wait(&status);

        }

        else if (pid == 0) {
            execute(myarg);

        }
```

and here is the execute function:
void execute(int argc) {

```
switch (argc) {

case 1:
    execlp(arg[0], arg[0], NULL);
case 2:
    execlp(arg[0], arg[0], arg[1], NULL);
case 3:
    execlp(arg[0], arg[0], arg[1], arg[2], arg[3], NULL);
case 4:
    execlp(arg[0], arg[0], arg[1], arg[2], arg[3], arg[4], NULL);
default:
    printf("Error in switch\n");
}
```

my problem is normally if we meet case 1~4, there is no problem. but if we meet default, the hard code for exiting shell only work if I type exit with equal amount of of "Error in switch" i got. Help me!!!

Result when I don't get "Error in switch":

```
kevinshell>> ls  
myshellw.c  posix  posix.c  posix.c~  shell-l.c~  test  test.c`
kevinshell>> exit
```

and here is when there is error:

```
kevinshell>> stuff
Error in switch
kevinshell>> stuff
Error in switch
kevinshell>> another
Error in switch
kevinshell>> exit
kevinshell>> exit
kevinshell>> exit
kevinshell>> exit
```

Comment: IMHO you should have a look to `execvp` which is tailored for arbitrary parameters number ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call exit after the printf in the default case. Otherwise your child process never exits...

The reason this works for cases 1-4 is that exec* calls are replacing the current process image with the requested program and eventually, that program calls exit

From man exec:

> The  exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with
>          a new process image.  The functions described in this manual  page  are
>          front-ends  for execve(2).  (See the manual page for execve(2) for fur‐
>          ther details about the replacement of the current process image.)

If you post the complete code, I'll be able to further explain what the child is doing after the printf line (I'm guessing it forks again as a normal shell would run this code in a loop)